# Unable to Insert stored procedure results into temp table for Babelfish Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-rds-data-service, babelfish

I'm having trouble inserting the results of a stored procedure into a table variable in Babelfish Aurora Postgres (AWS). Here's the code I'm using:

```
declare @temp TABLE (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 nvarchar(max))

insert into @temp (col1, col2, col3, col4)

EXEC [dbo].[test_proc]

select * FROM @temp
```

Definition of Stored Procedure:

```
create proc dbo.test_proc
as
begin
select 1 as col1, 1 AS col2, 24 as col3, 'sample value' as col4
end
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can someone help me understand what might be the issue or suggest an alternative approach? Temporary table is also not working for same.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Does Babelfish show you the Postgres SQL it generated from that T-SQL?

Comment: We need to see the source of `some_stored_proc`. If that procedure is just a `SELECT` query then you should convert it to a TVF or `VIEW` instead of it being a `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: @siggemannen some weird error staging dbo schema does not exists.

Comment: Did you try to remove the [dbo]. part?

Comment: @Dai In Babelfish Table Valued Function does not work as it works in SQL Server So basically some_stored_proc returns table based result in the form of col1, col2, col3, col4 based on parameters.

Comment: @siggemannen I did. It is just a stupid error. If you just run EXEC [dbo].[some_stored_proc] param1, param2 I get the result. It is only when I try putting that result into some table I get error.

Comment: Strange, it doesn't mention this limitation in the docs.

Comment: `ERROR:  schema "dbo" does not exist` is explainable. Babelfish is a TDS (Tabular Data Streams) proxy that allows Microsoft SQL Server client stacks to connect to a Postgres SQL server on the backend. Although it mostly uses T-SQL syntax there are still things bound by Postgres rules. If you execute `select nspname from pg_catalog.pg_namespace order by nspname;` do you see that the default schemas are `information_schema`, `pg_catalog`, `pg_toast` and `public`? Have you tried to create a `dbo` named schema and then objects within it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried creating just the dbo, but at the back it attaches itself to master, like it creates master_dbo, which again brings back to the original problem. However, the question is, why am I not able to insert stored procedure results into a temporary table?

Comment: There are some known issues with INSERT..EXECUTE. Some of those will be addressed in the upcoming Babelfish release v.3.4.  If you can post a reproduction, I can check whether your issue will be fixed.

Comment: @RobV What do you mean by post a reproduction?

Comment: Reproduction: a minimal but complete set of SQL statements that can be executed on their own to demonstrate the issue

Comment: The definition of [some_stored_proc] is missing

Comment: @RobV updated definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v.3.4.0, this works fine provided you remove the schema name from the proc execution, e.g. EXEC [test_proc] . In earlier Babelfish releases this fails.
The schema name should obviously be allowed to be specified and that is an outstanding issue - note that this applies only to INSERT..EXECUTE, not to regular proc executions.